# Redirect in Ajax Post Response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm probably missing something huge here, but it seems I can't redirect my ajax response for a reason I really don't understand, could anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
   (function($){
     function processForm( e ){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'z1.php',
          dataType: 'html',
          type: 'post',
          contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          data: $("#purchases").serialize(),
          processData: false,
          success: function(data){
            if(data == "success") {
               window.location.href = 'zzz.php';
            }

            if(data == "error") {
                window.location.href = 'xxx.php';
            }
         }
      });

         e.preventDefault();
    }

        $('#purchases').submit( processForm );
  })(jQuery);
```

Apparently if I take off the `preventDefault()` the ajax post doesn't even work properly, he submit the form but the response isn't quite complete...

I just want to process my Form and use ajax post and depends on what he returns redirect to a specific url with a message.

Comment: prevent the form submission before you try to make the ajax call

Comment: Could you elaborate in the code please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error sentence might be

`if(data == "success") {window.location.href = 'zzz.php';}`. You are directly refering if data is having success. Might be the success must be in some other property, which you need to refer. Didi you console how you `data` is comming. Is it a JSON structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write code in submit() method as paremeter and use return false at end of function

```
(function($){
$('#purchases').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'z1.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: $("#purchases").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            if(data == "success") {
               alert("success");
               document.location.href = 'zzz.php';
            }

            if(data == "error") {
                alert("Error");
                document.location.href = 'xxx.php';
            }
         }
      });
   return false;
});
})(jQuery);
```

Also make sure server response only "success" or "error" text.

Comment: It is returning me only the string "success" and even tho it won't redirect me after processing the ajax...

Comment: can you please check console log?

Comment: The console.log returns me the string "success"

Comment: try with  `document.location.href ` instead of  `window.location.href`

Comment: My success: function doesn't even answer my calls, I tried to alert something and nothing showed up, but in the console the ajax is responding ok, what could be happening?

Comment: I am not talking about AJAX request status I am taking about ajax  response?.. it might be blank... so please check with your php script.

Comment: "200 OK Response: success" That's what ajax showed up.

Comment: you have to check response of that ajax request... in console network tab or Net tab

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#purchases").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'z1.php',
      dataType: 'html',
      type: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data: $("#purchases").serialize(),
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){
        if(data == "success") {
           window.location.href = 'zzz.php';
        }

        if(data == "error") {
            window.location.href = 'xxx.php';
        }
     }
  });

});
```

});

Try this code.

Comment: It is a SoapCall to a webservice, the response of this php is a XML string, then I put the following test: `if (strpos($reply, 'APPROVED') !== false) { echo 'success'; }`